# Flutter Bloc with ProxyProvider error: Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I'm trying to provide a Bloc to my app that is dependant on another service. Inside that Bloc I'm listening to streams from the injected service. It's throwing this error:

```
Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (UserBloc).


- ListenableProvider
- ChangeNotifierProvider
- ValueListenableProvider
- StreamProvider

Alternatively, if you are making your own provider, consider using InheritedProvider.
...
```

This is the code for my providers, there's more, but these are causing problems:

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<AuthService>(create: authServiceBuilder),
    ProxyProvider<AuthService, DatabaseService>(
      update: (_, authService, __) => databaseBuilder(_, authService),
    ),
    ProxyProvider<DatabaseService, UserBloc>(
      create: (_) => UserBloc(),
      update: (_, database, bloc) => bloc..updateDependencies(database),
      dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.close(),
    ),
    ProxyProvider<UserBloc, ProfileBloc>(
      create: (_) => ProfileBloc(),
      update: (_, userBloc, bloc) => bloc..updateDependencies(userBloc),
      dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.close(),
    ),
  ]
)
```

The Blocs are throwing the errors, other services work fine.

I tried creating the Blocs in the update parameter of the ProxyProvider, similar to the DatabaseService ProxyProvider above but that doesn't work.

I then made it so that I'm creating the Blocs in the create parameter, and when update is called, I unsubscribe from any streams and resubscribe, and then call the Blocs `close()` method on dispose. But it's showing the same error.

This is roughly what my UserBloc looks like:

```dart
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  DatabaseService _database;

  /// The UI will always reflect this local cache.
  final _userCache = BehaviorSubject<User>();

  StreamSubscription<User> _userSub;
  StreamSubscription<User> _userCacheSub;

  UserBloc() {
    // When the cache updates, update the UI immediately.
    _userCacheSub = _userCache.listen((user) => add(UserUpdated(user)));
  }

  void updateDependencies(DatabaseService database) {
    // Store a new reference to the database.
    _database = database;

    // Cancel existing subscriptions
    if (_userSub != null) _userSub.cancel();

    // Database is always the source of truth. Push upates straight to the cache
    _userSub = _database.userStream.listen((user) => _userCache.add(user));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSub.cancel();
    _userCacheSub.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Whats the best way to have Bloc to Bloc dependency? Do I have to have them under a consumer and provide it below or is there a way to have it working with ProxyProvider?

Comment: The problem is Bloc is an abstract class that extends Stream, so you should try to use StreamProvider, also in the last Proxy provider shouldn't be ProxyProvider<DatabaseService, ProfileBloc>?

Comment: @EdwynZN Oh yes my bad, i copied my code across wrong. Okay I think that makes sense then. Is there a way to Proxy a StreamProvider? I can't seem to find something in the docs

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it safety with provider + Bloc, maybe with some Stateful widget, does DatabaseService needs to be saved as a reference in the other Bloc? Is it used anywhere?

Comment: It's actually more the UserBloc to ProfileBloc dependency I'm trying to get working.
The UserBloc has a bunch of logic to update some User preference data. But I also have a profile page which also needs to update the user document. I wanted to keep the logic for updating the user in one place while keeping the two blocs separate.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but it can be a bit tricky, have you tried the inbuilt classes MultiBloc, RepositoryProvier, etc from the flutter_bloc package, I understand they use provider inside, maybe using only flutter_bloc with those functions can be a bit easier than managing classes and Blocs by separate and then added them in in a Provider